how can i get user's inviter in public group
I'm trying to link a new user to his inviter.
But I can not find any information about inviter in "chat_join_request" event.
Is there any solution to find out which invite link a user uses to join the group.
bot.on('chat_join_request', async (msg) => {
    console.log("new member", msg)
}

no invite_link prop in msg

please don't use unrelated tags

You can't do that this way on a public chat.
The ChatJoinRequest.invite_link will always be null/undefined for public group join requests. This is because, the user is actually getting into the group once an Admin approves the request. So, that's not somehow related to the invite link anyway.
Here's a discussion thread on TDLib chat on Telegram about this.

Old Answer (not relevant)
On private chats you can follow this procedure:
If you want to map the user to their inviter, you should generate new invite link for each inviter with createChatInviteLink method, you can make use of the the name parameter to distinguish the user later if you want to (this is simple way) or you can use a database to map link to the inviter.
If you are using the name parameter, you can easily get the invite link's name from Update.chat_join_request.invite_link.name.
I'll briefly explain the flow:

Inviter with user id 1234 sends /generate command
Bot generates a new invite link with createChatInviteLink with name set to "u1234"
Inviter sends link to another user (user_id: 9876) and they tries to join the group.
The Update.chat_join_request event is triggered and the following code can do the rest:

bot.on('chat_join_request', async (up) => {
    console.log("New Request", up)
    const name = up.chat_join_request.invite_link.name;

    // Removes the "u" from name ("u1234") and we added earlier and gets the `user_id` of the inviter as integer.
    const inviterId = parseInt(name.slice(1)); 
    
    // you can call getChat or getChatMember to get more info on the inviter here

    // ...
})

Hope this helps.

it is useful in private group but doesn't work in public group.

Hmm, didn't know that. I just tried It seems like ChatJoinRequest.invite_link is always null. Yeah, you're right. Here's a discussion on the TDLib chat on Telegram about this. Seems like this is a intended behavior as of now. So, there's no way to actually get the invite link by which the user is trying to join and hence the inviter.
